# Two input streams to the node in mediapipe

Tags: android, computer-vision

I'm trying to modify Google Mediapipe example ObjectDetection by adding a second input stream to DetectionLabelIdToText node. I want to send to calculator some extra data (for example, label names instead of load from file).

I modify object_detection_mobile_gpu.pbtxt

```
input_stream: "second_input"
...
node {
  calculator: "DetectionLabelIdToTextCalculator"
  input_stream: "filtered_detections"
  input_stream: "SECOND:second_input"
  output_stream: "output_detections"
  node_options: {
    [type.googleapis.com/mediapipe.DetectionLabelIdToTextCalculatorOptions] {
      label_map_path: "mediapipe/models/ssdlite_object_detection_labelmap.txt"
    }
  }
}
...
```

and add

```
cc->Inputs().Get("SECOND", 0).Set<int>();
```

to detection_label_id_to_text_calculator.cc.

I expect nothing changes and app will works like without modification, but after adding a second input stream to node calculator's method Process isn't called at all.

What I am doing wrong? Similar case is explained into documentation as example calculator.

Links:
[Example code](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/objectdetectiongpu)
[Explained calculator code](https://mediapipe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/calculator.html#example-calculator)

Answer (score 0):

The DetectionLabelIdToTextCalculator calculator might not be designed to take two inputs. The subgraph definition for DetectionLabelIdToTextCalculator could be looked into.

I had a similar situation, and merging the two input sources as an OpenCV matrix before inputting to MediaPipe worked for me.